# How do I conditionally loop in Python?

Tags: python, dice

I have been trying but struggling to make a rolling dice simulator in Python that is an assignment for school and am looking for some help for it. These are the instructions:

> This project involves writing a program that simulates rolling a dice.
>   When the program runs, it will randomly choose a number between 1 – 6.
>   Have the dice roll 100 times. The program will count if it is a 1 or 2
>   or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6. After rolling the dice 100 times the program will
>   output how many times each number was rolled. It should then ask you
>   if you’d like to roll again, answer (1 for Yes) and (0 for No).
>
> What you will be Using : Variables Integer Random Print For Loop
>   and/or While Loop

I have two sections of code that I need to loop over:

```py
    import random
    for x in range(100):
       value = random.randint(1, 6)
       print(value)
```

and:

```py
    value = input("Wanna roll? 1 yes 2 no:\n")
    print(f'You entered {value}')
    y={value}
    while y=1
    print(value)
```

What is an idiomatic way of doing this in Python?

Comment: Show us the code you've written so far.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for information on asking a question that will lead to a good solution to your problem. In the meantime can you please post what code you have tried so far?

Comment: so far i put this but idk if its right

Comment: I would suggest putting the code you've written in the body of your question (using a code block, for readability). If you're just getting started with python, the python tutorial (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) might help; otherwise, if you have a specific python question, make sure that is clear.

Comment: A previous comment suggested the "how to ask" page.  Again, please follwo that protocol.

Comment: Okay, I added it to the body of the paragraph

Comment: Put the 1st code into a function, then call that in the `while` block of the 2nd code and counting how many times you've called it. Repeat the loop *while* the count is not yet 100. See [How do I repeat a program in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41365922/2745495).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I repeat the program in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41365922/how-do-i-repeat-the-program-in-python)