# How do I open another file in python? (not .txt file)

Tags: python

Ok so I want to make a very very very very very simple coin flipping program and I want to make it so the player can choose if to close after the coin flipped or if to flip again. This is the code I used, the person can type either 1 or 2, and choose if to flip again or if to close the program, I tried using `open("Coinflip.py)` but it didn't do anything. What should I do?

```
import random 
import time  
flip = random.randint(1, 2)  
if flip == 1:     
    print("The coin landed heads")  
if flip == 2:     
    print("The coin landed tails")   
print('') 
print("")  
time.sleep(1)  
choice = int(input("Type 1 to exit or 2 to flip again and press enter "))  
if choice == 1:     
    exit()  
elif choice == 2:     
    open("Coinflip.py") 
input()
```

Comment: You want to run another python process, from an already running python process? This is called Multiprocessing https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html

Comment: @TomMcLean this might be overkill. Instead it sounds like they should instead use a [`while`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html)-loop, to repeat the same code again.

Comment: @Mime Yep, no idea without any code though

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: @Lenntror `import random
import time

flip = random.randint(1, 2)

if flip == 1:
    print("                                   The coin landed heads")

if flip == 2:
    print("                                   The coin landed tails")


print('')
print("")

time.sleep(1)

choice = int(input("                   Type 1 to exit or 2 to flip again and press enter "))

if choice == 1:
    exit()

elif choice == 2:
    open("Coinflip.py")

input()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I repeat the program in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41365922/how-do-i-repeat-the-program-in-python). Besides that, you should read the [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/)

Comment: btw i couldnt add an image

Comment: You should never add the code as image, instead add it as text in the question by surrounding it with tripple backticks. Please also read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a function and a while loop to continuously ask for coin flips:

```
import random
import time

def coin_flip():
    flip = random.randint(1, 2)
    if flip == 1:
        print("The coin landed heads")
    if flip == 2:
        print("The coin landed tails")
    time.sleep(1)


def main():
    while True:
        choice = int(input("Type 1 to exit or 2 to flip again"))
        if choice == 1:
            break
        elif choice == 2:
            coin_flip()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

*technically you don't need a function, but lets use one anyway*